# C++ vector not saving the parent of an object

Tags: c++, class, vector, reference

Suppose I Have `class A`  like this

```
class A {
    public:int num;
    public:A* parent;

    A(){};

    A::A (const A &s)
    {
        this->num = s.num;
    }
};
```

Inside the main function I  make two object from class A

```
int main()
{
    A a1;
    a1.num = 2;
    
    A a2 = a1;
    a2.parent = &a1;
    
    cout << a2.parent->num << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

it will obviously print 2 but when I make a vector of class A and push a2 object into the vector like this

```
int main()
{
    A a1;
    a1.num =2;
    
    A a2 = a1;
    a2.parent = &a1;
    
    vector <A> List;
    List.push_back(a2);
    

    A temp = List.front();
    
    cout << temp.parent->num << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

cmd is crashing and its not printing anything . Could anyone help me .

PS: I didn't know what is the correct way to assign the second object into the parent of the first object inside the deep copy constructor that's why I assigned it manually .

Comment: Your `A` copy-constructor only copies `num`, it doesn't copy or otherwise initialize the `parent` member variable. So `temp.parent` will be uninitialized with an *indeterminate* value, leading to *undefined behavior* when you dereference the pointer.

Comment: Simple workaround for this specific example: Remove the copy-constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
A::A (const A &s)
{
        this->num = s.num;
}
```

This is a copy constructor. It is triggered on `A temp = List.front();`

However, it doesn't set `this->parent`, which remains uninitialized. So, next line, when you do `temp.parent->num` you access uninitialized memory.

You should also do: (Or remove it altogether as Some Programmer dude suggests)

```
A::A (const A &s)
{
        this->num = s.num;
        this->parent = s.parent;
}
```

But take some time to look up on the rule of three. And know that `vector`s will reallocate and may invalidate the address of some objects. This will come to bite you if you set an object from a vector as a parent of another one.

Comment: is there an alternative for vector to avoid such problems ?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the full use case, but having a vector of pointers to `A` sometimes works. Or if you have all the `A`s in the same vector you could store hte index of the parent instead of a pointer to it. Basically, go pointers all around, or don't use pointers at all. Vectors have value semantics, so a mixed approach will lead to problems.